# Get web table value with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am experiencing a problem in extracting data from [this website](http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT).

I tried with an Excel web query (which generally works with other pages in the website, but it fails to retrieve data for this specific website).

I managed by "inspecting the element" of the webpage to use responsetext and manipulate the text, but in this case I found that the body has "Text - Empty Text Node" which makes pratically impossible to work with text.

Comment: The link you provided did not work. What kind of data are you trying to extract?

Comment: Hi @Ian O'Brien, the link does not work using google chrome but it work fine with internet explore.

Comment: @IanO'Brien i am new to this forum here the website [bmreports] (http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT/) I am not sure whether i can use HTML in VBA for this sort of data, the problem is that some page in [bmrport.com] are well formatted , some like (http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT/) are quite complicate to deal with. Below a sample of the HTML code i would like to get information from:                                                                        
<th class="header">DATE</th>
<th class="header">S/P</th>
Thanks

Comment: That page has a export to csv option... does that not contain the relevant data?

Comment: @Pynner yes it does, and it is exactly what i want, but i do not know how to click on the cvs and save the the file using vba. ideally i should be able to set an outomation which goes on that web page either extract date from HTML or click on the cvs and save the file. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't love it, but it's the best I could come up with.  Change the Debug.Print line to something useful.  You'll need to set a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

```
Public Sub GetReports()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hTbl As MSHTML.HTMLTable

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Navigate2 "http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set hDoc = ie.document

    Set hTbl = hDoc.getElementsByClassName("tablesorter").Item(0)

    Debug.Print hTbl.innerText

    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: it is not perfect but it is a good starting point. have you got any ideaof how press the CSV bottom and save csv file?